# NSMutableArray adding into a cycle

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray, cycle

I have this...

```
allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
 [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"1" andDescription:@"Hi man!"],
 [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"2" andDescription:@"Hi woman"],
nil ];
```

How can I do something like that?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hi man",@"Hi woman",nil]; 
allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
   NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
   [[Food alloc] initWithName:aString andDescription:@"array[i]"];
}
```

...as well as enter through a cycle?

Comment: Strip the quotes and the at-mark, and it'll be fine.

Comment: What? I don't understand...

Comment: that's a problem. See the answer below.

Comment: @MarcoTini don't edit your question solving the mistake in the code, otherwise the answers below won't make sense. Just leave it there and mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hi man",@"Hi woman",nil]; 
allTableData = [NSMutableArray array];
for(i=0; i<[array count]; i++){
   NSString *aString = [@(i) stringValue];
   Food *food = [[Food alloc] initWithName:aString andDescription:array[i]];
   [allTableData addObject:food];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[Food alloc] initWithName:aString andDescription:@"array[i]"];
```

should be

```
[[Food alloc] initWithName:aString andDescription:array[i]];
```

In the first case you were adding the string `"array[i]"`, where instead you want to access the i-th element of the array.

Also, there's a shorter way for converting an `int` to `NSString`

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
```

can be replaced by

```
@(i).stringValue
```

The `@` syntax for numbers is a feature introduced by llvm 3.3, that allows you to create `NSNumbers` literals. `NSNumber` has then the method `stringValue` that you can use to get the desired `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hi man",@"Hi woman",nil];
NSMutableArray* tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:array.count];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj,NSUInteger index,BOOL* stop){

[tableData addObject:[[Food alloc] initWithName:[@(index) stringValue] andDescription:obj]];

}];
```